# Confidence interval for relative risk with uncertain incidences

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, relative-risk

The usual suggestion for computing a confidence interval for a relative risk estimate is to start from the variance:

$$
   \text{CI}_R = R \pm z \cdot \exp \sqrt{\sigma^2_{\log R}}
$$
where $R$ is the risk estimate, $z$ is the z-score for the desired confidence level, and
$$
   \sigma^2_{\log R} = \frac{|I| - A_I}{|I| \cdot A_I} + \frac{|C| - A_C}{|C| \cdot A_C}
$$
where $|I|$ and $|E|$ are the sizes of the intervention and control groups, and $A_I$ and $A_C$ are the number of affected individuals in each group.

But suppose that $A_I$ and $A_C$ themselves are uncertain (e.g. because they are predictions of a model).  We have values for $\sigma^2_{A_I}$ and $\sigma^2_{A_C}$ and we want to incorporate those uncertainties into the confidence interval.  Assuming incidence rates in each group are independent, we can compute the variance *of the variance* as

$$
\sigma^2[\sigma^2_{\log R}] = \frac{\partial^2 \sigma^2_{\log R}}{\partial\, A_I^{\,2}} \sigma^2_{A_I} + \frac{\partial^2 \sigma^2_{\log R}}{\partial\, A_C^{\,2}} \sigma^2_{A_C} = \frac{2 \sigma^2_{A_I}}{A_I^{\,3}} + \frac{2 \sigma^2_{A_C}}{A_C^{\,3}}
$$

And this is where I get stuck: I don't know how to combine $\sigma^2_{\log R}$ with $\sigma^2[\sigma^2_{\log R}]$ to get something to put into the original equation.

Any advice?